# Обновление чата

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php

Те, кто шарит, помогите, плс... Хочу сделать по типу чата, но встал вопрос:
окно с сообщениями у меня выводится через iframe и обновляется через refresh каждые 2сек, но когда сидишь в нем, он мигает и это немножко накаляет, как можно избавиться от мигания (обновления) и сделать по другому... Подскажите, и если можно, с примерчиком.

Comment: не путайте, пожалуйста, java и javascript, java к вашему вопросу мало относится

Comment: ну тут без ajax никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант: каждые несколько секунд отправляется ajax-запрос на сервер, и только если он возвращает результат «Чат обновлён» — фрейм перезагружается. Мигание всё равно будет, но не каждые две секунды, а только при появлении новых сообщений.

Сложный вариант: опять же ajax-запрос, но в ответе он приносит не просто флажок «обновился/не обновился», а полный текст новых сообщений. Этот текст добавляется в innerHTML фрейма (точнее, того его элемента, который содержит все сообщения; в простейшем случае это body). Только надо при этом отслеживать, чтобы общее число строк во фрейме не превысило разумного максимума (подсчитывать их и удалять старые сообщения, если надо).

Answer (score 1):

Простые аякс запросы это дорогое удовольствие с точки зрения ресурсов попробуйте использовать COMET, это по сути тот же аякс, с увеличенным временем ожидания ответа сервера, то есть из-за длительного открытого соединения, данные пересылаются постоянно.

Предлагаю вам [почитать о COMET подробнее](http://javascript.ru/AJAX/COMET)